# Must Number of equality constraints and decision variables be equal?

Tags: optimization, matlab, constraints

Must Number of equality constraints and decision variables in an optimization problem be equal ?

If not, how can I solve the equality constraint equations with a solver e.g. `fsolve`,`lsqnonlin`,  by considering the limits of decision variables in order to get a better initial point and also check the feasibility of the problem at the first place?

I am solving an optimization problem using `fmincon` with many constraints and decision variables but I am getting an infeasible `exit-flag`. So, I've tried to solve all equality constraints as a nonlinear system with `fsolve` to get a better initial point and also check the feasibility of the problem. Since `fsolve` cannot consider lower and upper limits of the variables, it returns a solution which hits the limits of decision variables. Then I have tried to solve it with `lsqnonlin` function as it is able to take upper and lower limits of variables into account. But `lsqnonlin` cannot be run and gives an error like that,

```
The Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm does not handle bound
constraints and the trust-region-reflective algorithm
requires at least as many equations as variables;
aborting.
```

I guess it means, the number of variables and equations (equality constraints) are not equal.
Also, as an other attempt I've performed `fmincon` with constant zero objective function considering the varibles limits. By `active-set` option I am getting my original initial point. Also by `interior-point` option I am getting a totally different solution which is in the bounds.

```
opts = optimoptions(@fmincon,'Algorithm','interior-point','Display','off');
  x = fmincon(@(x)0,Dat.InitialGuess,[],[],[],[],lb,ub,@(X) fminconstr(X,Dat,D),opts)
```

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: In general, the answer must be no. But some specific algorithm might make that requirement.

Comment: Thanks for answer. That problem has been solved few days ago. I m now having another problem. If you are interested please look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30273210/choosing-and-setting-of-fmincon-optimization-solver) and [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30237483/getting-exit-flag-0-2-with-sqp-algorithm-of-fmincon-matlab-function)

Comment: If you have solved your own problem, you should consider writing it up as an answer here!

Comment: sure, I will do. But it's a huge problem and I am so busy in solving it. I will write an asnwer to this question and other questions that I've asked and solved in stackexchange. @kjetilbhalvorsen